# How to create a CSS GRID with 3 distinct head elements

Tags: html, css, grid

I get a list using the CSS display: grid as shown below
[image]

My task has to be edited so that the list will look like this when it is displayed on PC, while on my mobile it will look like the first image.
The first 3 elements will be larger than the rest.
And responsive support

[image]

Here is my code:

HTML:

```css
.grid {
    width: 638px;
    display: grid;
    grid-row-gap: 68px;
    grid-column-gap: 12px;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(140px, 1fr));
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
   border: 3px solid green;
   width: auto;
   height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

I tried to fix it but it doesn't work like, thanks everyone!

Comment: flexbox is more suitable here

Comment: @TemaniAfif thank! but this is the source code available, I am only allowed to use GRID, because it applies to many existing pages

Comment: btw few things about the css code: `justify-content` is an attribute for flexboxes. As you not using `display: flex;` it is useless and can be removed. The use of minmax within this grid has no effect. The columns will always have the same width as the grid width and column count is fixed. There for you could simply use `grid-template-columns: repeat(x, 1fr);`. `grid template-rows: auto auto;` can be shortend to: `grid-auto-rows: auto;` or left altogether as it is the default value anyways. Last but not least, `.item { width: auto;}` is the default grid card value and can be removed aswell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may rethink it from a 12 columns grid and reset grid-column spanning to the item.

possible example

```css
.grid {
    width: 638px;
    display: grid;
    grid-row-gap: 68px;
    grid-column-gap: 12px;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(35px, 1fr));/* 35 x 4 = 140 */
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
   border: 3px solid #4285F4;
   border-radius:3px;
   width: auto;
   height: 150px;
   grid-column:auto / span 4; /* about 35px X 4 of width */
   margin-right:8px;
}
.item:nth-child(3), .item:nth-child(3)~.item {
margin-right:0;
}
.item:nth-child(3)~.item {
grid-column:auto / span 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

spanning columns rules and grid-template-columns can be reset via the mediaquerie your want to use.

Comment: Thank you! it work well, but I have a question: How do I get the first 3 elements grid-column-gap: 20px; ? thanks

Comment: oups, add a margin , i'll update the snippet

Comment: @HoangTran updated the snippet to increase the visual gap of the first row.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a number that contains 3 and 4 as multiplicator. For example 12. So You divide the grid into `12 columns`. Then you use `nth-child` pseudo selctor to selct the first 3 and give them a `span of 4` and every other child a `span of 3`.

with `:nth-child(-n+3)` you select the first 3 elements. As you want them to be 3 boxes in one row the need to `span 4` to fit the `12 columns`.

with `:nth-child(n+3)` you select all element with exeption of the first 3. Now you need to let them `span 3` columns to fit 4 boxes within the 12 column wide row.

```css
.grid {
    width: 638px;
    display: grid;
    grid-row-gap: 68px;
    grid-column-gap: 12px;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
}

.item {
   border: 3px solid green;
   height: 150px;
}

.item:nth-child(n+3) {
  grid-column: span 3;
}

.item:nth-child(-n+3) {
  grid-column: span 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```